# How to call child class function from parent class PHP

Tags: php, class

I want to deveope private framework to build my application in future with PHP. My sample code is:

```
class system {
    const token = "1234";
}

class data extends system {
    public $driver = "mysql";

    function get_name() {
        if (parent::token == "1234") {
            return "John";
        }
    }
}

class about extends system {
    public $version = "10.1";
    function get_build() {
        if (parent::token == "1234") {
            return "920";
        }
    }
}
```

My question is may i possible to call child function with including class structure. I don't know what the exactly name of this. I think something like this.

```
$system = new system();

echo $system->data->driver; // Output "mysql"
echo $system->data->get_name(); // Output "John"
echo $system->about->version; // Output "10.1"
```

In LUA the code is like this:

```
system = {};

system.token = "1234";
system.data.driver = "mysql";

function system.data.get_name()
    if (system.token == "1234") then
        return "John";
    end
end

system.about.version = "10.1";

function system.about.get_build()
    if (system.token == "1234") then
        return "920";
    end
end
```

Usage:

```
name = system.data.get_name() -- variable "name" value will be "John"
```

Thanks.

EDIT:

That code is only sample to show what i want to achieve, since i just starting to work in PHP. Usualy i'm using LUA. My plan is building framework that easy to use and also easy to understand. So people will be get easy way to build application and they can remember the function reference easily. For example:

`$tbl_result = $system->data->select("name", "table", "id='10'");`

This code is used to easy select data from database without querying. The return value is array list. Also this function is automaticaly detect the database driver from the configuration. So users doesn't need to know SQL query in spesific driver. But the method to call the function is should be structured. Why i have to use system->data->function? Because i will have system, component, and module as root. Then every root will have many child. For example, system will have core, data, model, etc. Maybe in each root will have same child name. So this is reason why i have to build this structure.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason that data class and about class should extend from system class. You can do the following instead.

```
class data {
    public $driver = 'mysql';
    public $token;
    function __construct($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
    }
    function get_name() {
        if ($this->token == "1234") {
            return "John";
        }
    }
}

class about {
    public $version = "10.1";
    public $token;
    function __construct($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
    }
    function get_build() {
        if ($this->token == "1234") {
            return "920";
        }
    }
}

class system {
    public $token;
    public $about;
    public $data;

    function __construct($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
        $this->about = new about($this->token);
        $this->data = new data($this->token);
    }   
}
```

Then you can do something like this.

```
$system = new system('1234');
echo $system->data->driver; // Output "mysql"
echo $system->data->get_name(); // Output "John"
echo $system->about->version; // Output "10.1"
```

I am just showing that this is one way of doing what you want to achieve. HOWEVER, I would re-think about the design and structure of your framework before doing anything with it.

Comment: By this way, you'll get multiple `$token` variable, it means using more memory. I understand the @NanangElSutra , using inheritance will prevent creating new variable, objects. To solve this question, you can set `static` for methods you want to access from parent class on the child class. You can access to them like : `data::get_name()`

Answer (score 0):

Thats not exactly how OOP works in PHP and is not what OOP is for in general.

if you want to access all of the child functions of the child classes you do not want to instantiate a system object you want to instantiate an about object:

```
$system = new about();
echo $system->driver; // Output "mysql"
echo $system->get_name(); // Output "John"
echo $system->version; // Output "10.1"
```

I would do some reading on PHP OOP though.

Comment: Yes, i have know about that. That is what usually i do. But i want to my code structure is easy to understand. If i use `$system->driver`, then if someone read that code, they will be think that the "driver" is system driver, not data driver. But if i can use the structure like in LUA (`system.data.driver`), people who read that code will be think that the "driver" is child of data, not of system. If it's not possible in PHP, then i will use the general way. :)